# '%matplotlib' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed matplotlib but the console doesn't recognise it as a command.

In case it helps, the same happend with jupyter notebook and I ended up havig to access it through the command python -m notebook. Can someone help please?

Comment: `matplotlib` isn't a command you run from the Command Prompt. It's a module you import into python with `import matplotlib as plt`

Answer (score -1):

"matplotlib" is not an executable command. It is a python library thus can only be used in a python interpreter, not in the Command Prompt or any other Shell for that matter.

The command you mentioned:

```
python -m notebook
```

works because "python" is an executable command. I suggest you brush up on Shell Commands and Scripting to gain some more understanding on this matter.

To use the matplotlib Library in the console. Do so, Please note that this will just open the Python Interpreter in the console and the matplotlib command won't be an executable command here either.

```
python
```

Once in the Python console:

```
import matplotlib
```

Here you can access the python libraries you have installed by importing them as above.